# How to change color of text in JavaFX Label

Tags: css, javafx

I am having trouble changing colors of text that are within the JavaFX label class.

This is the code I have so far.

```
package Problem2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Problem2Code extends Application {

Slider[] slider = new Slider[4];
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Text text = new Text("Show Colors");

    // Bottom pane
    Label[] labels = new Label[4];
    String[] stringLabels = {"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Opacity"};

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(30);
    gridPane.setVgap(5);
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(25));

    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    for (int i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
        slider[i] = new Slider();
        slider[i].setMin(0);
        if (!stringLabels[i].equals("Opacity")) {
            slider[i].setMax(255);
            slider[i].setValue(255);
        } else {
            slider[i].setMax(1);
            slider[i].setValue(1);
        }
        labels[i] = new Label(stringLabels[i]);
        slider[i].valueProperty()
                .addListener((obser, old, newV) -> text.setFill(getColor()));

        gridPane.add(labels[i], 0, i);
        gridPane.add(slider[i], 1, i);

    }
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(text);
    stackPane.setPrefSize(315, 65);
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(stackPane);
    borderPane.setBottom(gridPane);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Color Changer");
    primaryStage.show();
}

private Color getColor() {
    // r g b o
    double[] rgb = new double[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++) {
        rgb[i] = slider[i].getValue();
    }
    return Color.rgb((int)rgb[0], (int)rgb[1], (int)rgb[2], rgb[3]);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}}
```

When I build it and play with the sliders, this is what it looks like.
[image: Color Changer]

How can I edit the colors of text "Red", "Green", and "Blue", so the text colors matches the words like this?

[image]

I believe it has to do something with making an HBox? I tried it with that but didn't know how to do it correctly. I also tried making variables stringLabels1, stringLabels2, stringLabels3, and stringLabels4 for each of the strings, but had trouble with that in the gridPane portion. Having trouble coding either of those.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Theoretically you could apply the style `"-fx-text-fill: " + colorName.toLowerCase()`, but that relies on you using the exact same strings as the css color names; furthermore for `#00ff00` you need to use `lime` not `green`. Another option would be setting the slider values accordingly and retrieving the color, but I'm not sure why this would be preferrable to `lablels[0].setTextFill(Color.RED);lablels[1].setTextFill(Color.LIME);lablels[2].setTextFill(Color.BLUE);`

Comment: unrelated: please stick to java naming conventions - you are doing except for the package name :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [Color#web](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
    slider[i] = new Slider();
    slider[i].setMin(0);
    labels[i] = new Label(stringLabels[i]);
    if (!stringLabels[i].equals("Opacity")) {
        slider[i].setMax(255);
        slider[i].setValue(255);
        labels[i].setTextFill(Color.web(stringLabels[i])); //css alternative: labels[i].setStyle("-fx-text-fill: " + stringLabels[i]);
    } else {
        slider[i].setMax(1);
        slider[i].setValue(1);
    }

    slider[i].valueProperty()
            .addListener((obser, old, newV) -> text.setFill(getColor()));

    gridPane.add(labels[i], 0, i);
    gridPane.add(slider[i], 1, i);
}
```

---

Side note: you could use one listener for all four sliders:

```
ChangeListener<Number> listener = (obser, old, newV) -> text.setFill(getColor());

for (int i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
     ..
     slider[i].valueProperty().addListener(listener);
     ..
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Decided to use this method.

Answer (score 9):

Use `setTextFill` on label, below will set text color to Red:

```
labels[i].setTextFill(Color.color(1, 0, 0));
```